# Push Parse - launchOptions is null in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I know that this is a question already answered.

but after reading a lot of messages my problem is still here.

Using parse i sent this json push:

```
{"aps" : { "alert" : "text msg", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "chime" }, "_3Y" : "0"}
```

If app is active, then is all right, userInfo receive my data correctly:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
...
}
```

If the app is idle, the badge and the text notification appears but:

If I click on the text on notification bar, the app starts and I receive the push

If I click on the badge, the app starts but launchOptions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is null!

This is my test code for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    NSDictionary *aPushNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
//    NSDictionary* aPushNotification = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];

    NSString *test = [aPushNotification objectForKey:@"_3Y"];

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:test message:[aPushNotification description] delegate:NULL cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LOC018", @"Ok") otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
...
}
```

Maybe is a Parse problem ?

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

launchOptions is only set if the application is launched through the notification, if you launch it through the badge on the icon it starts without arguments, with launchOptions = nil.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution for it. I am facing this issue with launchOptions=nil.